# Trying to create a simple function that changes the background color of my page

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title says I am trying to create a function that achieves it.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var clickCount = 0;
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];

function changBgColor(color) {
    var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    bodyTag[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function changeBg() {
    changeBgColor(colors[clickCount]);
    clickCount++;

    clickCount = clickCount % bgColors.length;
}
```

When the function `changeBg()` is called from my html it does nothing and I'm scratching my head trying to understand why.

Comment: typo dude, your function changBgColor, I pretty sure it supposed to be changeBgColor

Answer (score 2):

There are some typos in your code.

```js
var clickCount = 0;
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];

function changeBgColor(color) {
  var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
  bodyTag[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function changeBg() {
  changeBgColor(colors[clickCount]);
  //---^------ missing e
  clickCount++;

  clickCount = clickCount % colors.length;
  // array variable name ---^^^^^^---
  
  // you can combine the above 2 lines if needed
  // clickCount = ++clickCount % colors.length;
  
  // or all 3 lines
  // changeBgColor(colors[ clickCount++ % colors.length]);
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeBg()">click</button>
```

Comment: nice work - I just posted the exact some solution as you - so rather than cluttering up the page with identical posts - I deleted mine. well done :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake while declaring funtion 'changBgColor'. You are missing an 'e'.

Also you are doing ***clickCount % bgColors.length;***, bgColors is not defined here. use ***colors.length*** instead

```js
var clickCount = 0;
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];

function changeBgColor(color) {
var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
bodyTag[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function changeBg() {
changeBgColor(colors[clickCount]);
clickCount++;

clickCount = clickCount % colors.length;
}
```

```html
<button onClick='changeBg();'>change color</button>
```